# Block level synchronization

Tags: java, synchronization

What is the significance of parameter passed to synchronized?

```
synchronized(parameter)
{

}
```

to achieve block level synchronization. Somewhere I saw code like

```
class test
{
    public static final int lock = 1;

    ...

    synchronized(lock) {
       ...
    }
}
```

I don't understand the purpose of this code.

Can anyone give me a better example and/or explain it?

Answer (score 14):

It's the reference to lock on. Basically two threads won't execute blocks of code synchronized using the same reference at the same time. As Cletus says, a synchronized *method* is mostly equivalent to using `synchronized (this)` inside the method.

I very much hope that the example code you saw wasn't *quite* like that - you're trying to synchronize on a primitive variable. Synchronization only works on a monitor (via a reference) - even if it *were* legal code, `x` would be boxed, which would lead to some *very* odd behaviour, as some integers will always be boxed to the same references, and others will create a new object each time you box. Fortunately, the Java compiler realises this is a very bad idea, and will give you a compile-time error for the code you've posted.

More reasonable code is:

```
class Test
{
    private static final Object lock = new Object();

    ...

    synchronized(lock){
       ...
    }
}
```

I've made the lock private, and changes its type to `Object`. Whether or not it should be static depends on the situation - basically a static variable is usually used if you want to access/change static data from multiple threads; instance variables are usually used for locks when you want to access/change per-instance data from multiple threads.

Comment: That's true - will edit. (Static may well be okay, depending on the context.)

Comment: public and static lock also isn't good idea :-) Btw, in Java, integer 1 is always boxed to the very same object.

Comment: Peter: Indeed - hence the "some integers" bit. However, it would be very odd to see the behaviour change based on a change from 127 to 128. (I mistakenly thought it was valid but unfortunate code - but it turns out I was compiling the wrong file. Oops.)

Comment: True. I was also wondering if that was even legal code, but it turned out that it isn's possible.

Comment: @JonSkeet "as some integers will always be boxed to the same references, and others will create a new object each time you box"..can you please explain this? I do not see the possible side effects.

Comment: @Geek: Consider if `x` is an `int`. Values in the range -128 to 127 are *guaranteed* to be boxed to the same reference every time - whereas outside that range, it's implementation-specific. So on some implementations, two pieces of code synchronizing on a value of `x` would block each other - and on others they wouldn't.

Answer (score 10):

This:

```
public synchronized void blah() {
  // do stuff
}
```

is semantically equivalent to:

```
public void blah() {
  synchronized (this) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Some people don't like to use 'this' for synchronization, partly because it's public (in that the instance is visible to external code). That's why you end up with people using private locks:

```
public class Foo
  private final static String LOCK = new String("LOCK");

  public void blah() {
    synchronized (LOCK) {
      // do stuff
    }
  }
}
```

The benefit is that LOCK is not visible outside the class plus you can create several locks to deal with more fine-grained locking situations.

Comment: I think in this example you have to remove "static", because with "static" LOCK will work for all instances of the Foo class.

Comment: will the fact that strings are immutable in java affect the lock in any manner?

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of the `synchronized` statement is to make sure that in a multi-threaded application, only one thread can access a critical data structure at a given time.

For instance, if you let two threads change the same data structure at the same time, the data structure would be corrupted, then you typically protect it with a lock.

In the real world, consider an analog where a public toilet has a key, hanging in a central place. Before you can use the toilet, you need the key, not only to enter, but it's also a guarantee that nobody else will try to enter the same toilet at the same time. They'll have to wait for the key to become available.

This is how such a lock construct works.

The parameter to the `synchronized` keyword is the key in this case. You lock the key, do what you need to do, then you unlock the key to let others have access to it. If other threads tries to lock the key while it is currently being locked by another thread, that thread will have to wait.

Answer (score 3):

I can't explain it as it doesn't compile.  You cannot lock a primitive.

Another bad example would be to change it to

```
public static final Integer lock =1;
```

This is a bad idea as small auto-boxed primitives are cached and is likely to have strange side effects (if this is done more than once)

Comment: can you explain the side effects?

Answer (score 1):

The object instance that is passed in to synchronized is the "unit of locking". Other threads that execute that try to gain a lock on the same instance will all wait their turn.

The reason people use this rather than the method level synchronized keyword (which locks on the executing class object's instance) is that they might want a finer-grained or different thing to wait for locking on, depending on how their multi-threaded algorithm is designed.