# How to best interpret synchronized(this) keyword in Java?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronized

Just wondering how to best interpret the synchronized keyword in Java?
I know what it does (simply put), it locks a critical section for more than one thread to access using a lock object that every object has. So can I interpret `synchronized(this)` as a method call where the return value of `synchronized` is this lock object?

Comment: Answered here: [java syntax: “synchronized (this)”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264726/java-syntax-synchronized-this)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.1 "It computes a reference to an object", finds the associated monitor of that object and performs a lock action on that monitor.

Answer (score 0):

`synchronized` does not return any value. `synchronized(this)` locks on `this` instance, i.e. the lock object is `this`.

Note that locking on `this` is considered a bad coding practice.

Comment: From the Java Documentation "computes a reference..." does sound to me like it returns something, just not at the client level.

Comment: I don't know what do you mean "at client level". In any case synchronized() is not a function, it is a keyword and no, it does not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine `this` is a key and the synchronized block is a hotelroom. When you get the key, the room is yours and noone else can enter it. When you give the key back, someone else can get the key again to enter the room.

`synchronized` itself doesn't return anything. It is just a syntax to synchronize threads by using *locks*.

In our example the threads would be guests, a synchronized block would be a hotelroom and a lock is a key for a room. Any object can be a lock and `this` is an object.

Comment: The interesting thing would now be to know how "synchronization of threads using locks" works internally.

Comment: @TMOTTM You can check the internals of any open-souce JVM. In any case modern OS already have APIs for this.